# Extract Specific Rows from a Database using LINQ

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, linq

[image: Screen capture from SQL Server Management Studio]

I would want to extract records from the database base on the criteria that:

- The TransLog_Date is less than or equals 2017-08-08 and also on the TransactionType.
- Exclude the first row (marked with red box) becuase its TransLog_ShareBalance was reduced within the period as shown in row 2.
- Exclude rows 4 and 5 because they are also greater than the specified date of 2017-08-08

I have tried the following but I am getting errors as I am not good in LINQ. If you can help also in writing it in plain SQL too I would be grateful.

```
var transQuery = from t in db.TransactionsLogDbSet
                         where (t.TransactionType == TransactionType.PurchaseOfShares)
                                || (t.TransactionType == TransactionType.TransferOfShares)
                                || (t.TransactionType == TransactionType.BonusSharesDeclared)
                         group t by t.Transholder_ID into groupedTable
                         select (from t1 in groupedTable
                                 orderby t1.TransLog_Date
                                 descending
                                 select t1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: i thing the select statement is not correct..check the below answer and let me if it will work

Answer (score 0):

```
        var transQuery = (from t in db.TransactionsLogDbSet
                          where (t.TransactionType == TransactionType.PurchaseOfShares)
                                 || (t.TransactionType == TransactionType.TransferOfShares)
                                 || (t.TransactionType == TransactionType.BonusSharesDeclared)
                          orderby t.TransLog_Date
                          group t by t.Transholder_ID into groupedTable
                          select new { TransLog_ShareBalance = groupedTable.Key}).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Well, I copied and tried editing in Visual Studio but red lines allo over indicating code errors. Can you refined it well for especially if you can look at image and insert the column names into it for me.

Comment: @BismarkAttaFrimpong, I don't have table so i can not do it properly but i tried.. check edited code and adjust according to u